# How to direct the control in to another controller method after a button press

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I was asked to create a calculator as a web application using ASP.NET MVC5.

I have already created the calculator view and a controller to **view** that 'calculator view'. After a button press (Let's say, addition button) how can I direct the control to the logic of the button press?

I have two user input fields.. In the case of addition, I need to add two user inputs and display the answer. I have the logic written in a method of the controller, but I don't know how to direct the control to execute that method after the button press.Simply, I don't know how to route to the controller method.

Please help.Thanks in advance!

Comment: `model` does not contain any information about the user interface.` controller `provides model data to the view, and interprets user actions such as button clicks. check this links http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/model-view-controller-MVC and http://www.tomdalling.com/blog/software-design/model-view-controller-explained/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MVC. The Model has logic of data entities. 
The View render's the display items i.e. Front-end
In the Controller you will write the logic for flow of application.

In your case, you will write the logic in Controller.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to bind a method which includes an ajax call ,to the button.
The ajax call will direct the control to the relevant controller method.